# Firefox onLocationChange not always called

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, settimeout, xul

I am building a firefox extension that creates several hidden browser elements.

I would like to `addProgressListener()` to handle onLocationChange for the page that I load. However, my handler does not always get called.

More specifically, here's what I'm doing:

1. Create a browser element, without setting its `src` property
2. Attach it to another element
3. Add a progress listener listening for `onLocationChange` to the browser element
4. Call `loadURIWithFlags()` with the desired url and post data

I expect the handler to be called every time after 4, but sometimes it does not (it seems to get stuck on the same pages though).

Interestingly, if I wrap 3 and 4 inside a `setTimeout(..., 5000);` it works every time.

I've also tried shuffling some of the steps around, but it did not have any effect.

The bigger picture: I would like to be reliably notified when browser's `contentDocument` is that of the newly loaded page (after redirects). Is there a better way to do this?

**Update**: I've since opened a bug on mozilla's bug tracker with a minimal xulrunner app displaying this behavior, in case anybody wants to take a closer look: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=941414

Comment: can we get some code / fiddle ? How do you set your listener?

Comment: @Cracker0dks there is a minimal xulrunner app attached to the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=941414

Comment: I realize this is a reduced testcase, but what are you trying to accomplish? Why use onLocationChange instead of a simple load listener? Why a <browser> instead of an <iframe> or even a XmlHttpRequest?

Comment: I am actually doing it so that I *can* listen to the `load` event. When the browser element is first created, its `contentDocument` is not pointing at the right page (it points to about:blank). Only after the `onLocationChange` is fired is the `contentDocument` updated to point to the new page (or at least that's the earliest I've been able to find).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to respond to the second part of your statement. I need it to be a browser element because I need it to behave exactly as if the user was visiting the site, including executing javascript. Some sites defend against clickjacking by preventing being iframe'd, and an XmlHttpRequest would not "execute" the page. I need this to reliably work for all sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience developing with Firefox, I've found in some cases the initialization code for various elements acts as if it were asynchronous. In other words, when you're done executing

```
var newBrowser = window.document.createElement('browser');
newBrowser.setAttribute('flex', '1');
newBrowser.setAttribute('type', 'content');
cacheFrame.insertBefore(newBrowser, null);
```

, your `browser` may not actually be ready yet. When you add the delay, things have time to initialize, so they work fine. Additionally, when you do things like dynamically creating `browser` elements, you're likely doing something that very few have tried before. In other words, this sounds like a bug in Firefox, and probably one that will not get much attention.

You say you're using `onLocationChange` so that you can know when to add a `load` listener. I'm going to guess that you're adding the `load` listener to the `contentDocument` since you  mentioned it. What you can do instead is add the `load` listener to the `browser` itself, much like you would with an `iframe`. If I replace

```
newBrowser.addProgressListener(listener);
```

with

```
newBrowser.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  console.log('got here! ' + e.target.contentDocument.location.href);
}, false);
```

then I receive notifications for each `browser`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, newBrowser.addEventListener('load', f) does not work - f never gets called. I have also tried to create a bunch of browsers right away at the start of my app and bind the listener to them later, in order to get around the async issue. This did not work, which leads me to think that it's not a "browser is ready" issue. Another really peculiar thing that happens is if I include the assignment to the listener variable inside the setTimeout, it again doesn't work!

Comment: If you're actually using `newBrowser.addEventListener('load', f)` then you're missing the final parameter. I tried this with your code and it worked for me. If it doesn't then post your new code and we can see what's up.

Comment: Aha, the parameter should actually be true (it's false by default). Thanks!